# How to maximize pay with repeated toss of coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, gambling

repeated toss a coin and you can stop anytime and payoff is just #times you got head divided by total number of throws, how do you maximize your pay.

Does anyone have a clever strategy for this? This was changed from another problem I solved involving flipping over cards from a deck and being paid the fraction of red.  Also never saw a satisfying solution

Comment: I think this may have been asked before http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869573/optimal-stopping-in-coin-tossing-with-finite-horizon/869585#869585

Comment: good read thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the probability of head is $p$. Suppose you have thrown $n$ tosses and landed $a$ heads. And suppose you contemplate playing $m$ more tosses. The expected payoff of this is
$$
\frac{a+pm}{n+m}.
$$
This is greater than or equal to $\frac{a}{n}$ iff
$$
(a+pm)n-(n+m)a=m(np-a)\geq 0.
$$
So if $a>pn$, you shouldn't continue. If $a\leq np$, then you should continue.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. If $a - pn$ is sufficiently small (where "sufficiently small" depends on $n$), then you can reasonably expect that your ratio will exceed $a/n$ some time in the future.

Comment: Why is a-pn sufficiently small enough to say the ratio will increase?  it could go either way but more than half number of total coins being heads seems like the reasonable choice.

Comment: @niels: The ratio will probably be greater _at some time in the future_. (And it will probably be smaller at some time in the future, too, but you don't stop then.)

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you should stop whenever the ratio of heads to flips is greater than 1/2. Like obviously since there is no maximal number of flips you can "eventually" get this as the ratio so stoping when your ratio is lower is silly but you can't guarantee you will "eventually" get a higher ratio so if you ever do get that (example sequences H or THH) then you should stop.

Comment: See my comment to Kim Jong Un's answer.